# Javafx from a thread notify events to controller class for setting Label,Textfield based on model

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

In thread I run some code and I need update javafx ui elements that are in JsonOverviewController.
I don't want to pass ui elements in model or class controller.
I don't want this

```
        jfWatch = new WatchController();
        jfWatch.setPathDirectory(absPathSelDir);
        jfWatch.setMyJsonFilesTable(myJsonFilesTable);
        jfWatch.setMyIdTableColumn(myIdTableColumn);
        ...
        
        jfWatch.setMyStateLabel(myStateLabel);
        
        jfWatch.start();
```

The code below show that Label.TextField are pass to thread and in run method update them.

```
package it.einaudi.storejson;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import it.einaudi.storejson.model.ConnectionConfig;
import it.einaudi.storejson.model.JsonFile;
import it.einaudi.storejson.model.JsonFileManager;

public class JsonOverviewController {
    
    @FXML
    private Button myButton;
    
    @FXML
    private Label myDirWatch;
    
    @FXML
    private Label myCurrentJsonFileId;
    
    @FXML
    private Label myCurrentJsonFileName;
    
    @FXML
    private TextArea myCurrentJsonFileContent;
    
    @FXML
    private Button myImportButton;
    
    @FXML
    private TableView<JsonFile> myJsonFilesTable;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myIdTableColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myNameFileTableColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myStateTableColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField myConnFullurlField;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField myConnUsernameField;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField myConnPasswordField;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField myConnNamedbField;
    
    @FXML
    private Label myStateLabel;
    
    //private JsonWatchService threadJsonWatch;
    private WatchController jfWatch;
    
    private JsonFileManager jfManager;
    
    /**
     * The constructor (is called before the initialize()-method).
     */
    public JsonOverviewController() {       
        //threadJsonWatch = null;
        jfManager = null;
        jfWatch = null;
    }
    
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Button was clicked, do something...
        System.out.println("myButton premuto");
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        File selectedDirectory;
        Stage thisStage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        String absPathSelDir;
        
        selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(thisStage);
        if(selectedDirectory == null ) return;
        
        absPathSelDir = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
        
        myDirWatch.setText(absPathSelDir);
            
        if(jfWatch != null) jfWatch.interrupt();
        
        jfWatch = new WatchController();
        jfWatch.setPathDirectory(absPathSelDir);
        jfWatch.setMyJsonFilesTable(myJsonFilesTable);
        jfWatch.setMyIdTableColumn(myIdTableColumn);
        jfWatch.setMyNameFileTableColumn(myNameFileTableColumn);
        jfWatch.setMyStateTableColumn(myStateTableColumn);
        
        jfWatch.setMyCurrentJsonFileId(myCurrentJsonFileId);
        jfWatch.setMyCurrentJsonFileName(myCurrentJsonFileName);
        jfWatch.setMyCurrentJsonFileContent(myCurrentJsonFileContent);
        
        jfWatch.setMyStateLabel(myStateLabel);
        
        jfWatch.start();
        
        myStateLabel.setText("La cartella " + 
                             absPathSelDir + 
                             " è monitorata.");    
    }
    
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Handle Button event.
        myButton.setOnAction(this::handleButtonAction);
        
        myIdTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JsonFile,String>("idFile"));
        myNameFileTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JsonFile,String>("nameFile"));
        myStateTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<JsonFile,String>("stateFile"));
        
    }
    
}

public class WatchController extends Thread {
    
    private String pathDirectory;
    
    private Label myCurrentJsonFileId;
    
    private Label myCurrentJsonFileName;
    
    private TextArea myCurrentJsonFileContent; 
    
    private TableView<JsonFile> myJsonFilesTable;
    
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myIdTableColumn;
    
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myNameFileTableColumn;
    
    private TableColumn<JsonFile, String> myStateTableColumn;
    
    private Label myStateLabel;

    public void run() {
        if(!found) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileId.setText(""));
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileName.setText(""));
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText("Anteprima file json non disponibile."));  
        }else {
            final JsonFile firstJCopy = firstJ;
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileId.setText(firstJCopy.getIdFile()));
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileName.setText(firstJCopy.getNameFile()));
            
            fullPathFile = pathDirectory + "\\" + firstJ.getNameFile();
            System.out.println(fullPathFile);
            strJ = readFileAsList(fullPathFile);
            String strJCopy = strJ;
            Platform.runLater(() -> myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText(strJCopy));
        }
    }
}
```

On the contrary I want that my thread notify to controller that has occurred and send to controller some data of model. Thus in controller class based on data model a set Label,Textfield correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard MVC architecture, your model should contain a list of listeners, and should notify those listeners of events as needed. Your controller (which in JavaFX with FXML is more like a MVP presenter) should be a listener and should register itself with the model.

So:

```
public interface WatchListener {
    public void startedProcessing();
    public void fileProcessed(String data);
    public void notFound();
}
```

```
public class WatchController extends Thread {
    
    private String pathDirectory;
    
    private final List<WatchListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(WatchListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(WatchListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void run() {
        if(!found) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                listeners.forEach(WatchListener::notFound);
            }); 
        } else {
            final JsonFile firstJCopy = firstJ;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                listeners.forEach(WatchListener::startedProcessing);
            });
            
            fullPathFile = pathDirectory + "\\" + firstJ.getNameFile();
            System.out.println(fullPathFile);
            strJ = readFileAsList(fullPathFile);
            String strJCopy = strJ;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.fileProcessed(strJCopy));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public class JsonOverviewController implements WatchListener {
    
    // fields and initialize method as before
    
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Button was clicked, do something...
        System.out.println("myButton premuto");
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        File selectedDirectory;
        Stage thisStage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        String absPathSelDir;
        
        selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(thisStage);
        if(selectedDirectory == null ) return;
        
        absPathSelDir = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
        
        myDirWatch.setText(absPathSelDir);
            
        if(jfWatch != null) jfWatch.interrupt();
        
        jfWatch = new WatchController();
        watchController.addListener(this);
        jfWatch.setPathDirectory(absPathSelDir);
        
        jfWatch.start();
        
        myStateLabel.setText("La cartella " + 
                             absPathSelDir + 
                             " è monitorata.");    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void startedProcessing() {
        myCurrentJsonFileId.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileName.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText("Anteprima file json non disponibile.");
    }

    @Override
    public void fileProcessed(String data) {
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void notFound() {
        myCurrentJsonFileId.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileName.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText("Anteprima file json non disponibile.");  
    }
}
```

---

A better approach than using a plain thread here may be to use the JavaFX concurrent API and implement `WatchController` as a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). This has support for executing code for when the task is started, completes, etc., on the FX Application Thread (it basically handles all the `Platform.runLater()` calls for you as the state changes). This would look something like:

```
public class WatchController extends Task<String> {

    private final String pathDirectory;

    public WatchController(String pathDirectory) {
        this.pathDirectory = pathDirectory ;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        if(!found) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(pathDirectory + " not found");
        } else {
            final JsonFile firstJCopy = firstJ;
            fullPathFile = pathDirectory + "\\" + firstJ.getNameFile();
            System.out.println(fullPathFile);
            return readFileAsList(fullPathFile);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the controller:

```
public class JsonOverviewController implements WatchListener {

    // fields and initialize method as before

    private final Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // Button was clicked, do something...
        System.out.println("myButton premuto");
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(myButton.getScene().getWindow());
        if(selectedDirectory == null ) return;

        String absPathSelDir = selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath();

        myDirWatch.setText(absPathSelDir);

        if(jfWatch != null) jfWatch.cancel();

        jfWatch = new WatchController(absPathSelDir);
        watchController.setOnRunning(evt -> startedProcessing());
        watchController.setOnFailed(evt -> notFound());
        watchController.setOnSucceeded(evt -> fileProcessed(jfWatch.getValue());

        exec.execute(jfWatch);

        myStateLabel.setText("La cartella " + 
                             absPathSelDir + 
                             " è monitorata.");    
    }

    @Override
    public void startedProcessing() {
        myCurrentJsonFileId.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileName.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText("Anteprima file json non disponibile.");
    }

    @Override
    public void fileProcessed(String data) {
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void notFound() {
        myCurrentJsonFileId.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileName.setText("");
        myCurrentJsonFileContent.setText("Anteprima file json non disponibile.");  
    }
}
```

You probably need to do a little more work in the `Task` implementation to fully support cancelling the task in an appropriate way. See the [`Task` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for more details.